# Wrong img alt tag in duplicate product

Tags: image, magento, duplicates, product, sku

I notice that the image alt tag in the Magento frontend is not correct for a duplicated SKU.
It happens when I duplicate an SKU in Magento 1.9.2 backend.
In that case, the img alt tags of the duplicated product images, are the same as the img alt tags from the original SKU.
It doesn't help when I change the images of the duplicated SKU.

Magento does not show a warning for this.

Sounds familiar to anybody? Any suggestions on how to prevent or repair this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To repair this, you need to explicitly save the duplicated product in every store view on that product's "images" page.

Comment: Thanks, i had exactly the same problem. I can confirm this is the "solution" (even though it's a Magento bug).

Comment: Also confirmation from here - thanks for the link @AnnaVölkl